# Advanced Middle Game Attacking Tactics

Tags: learning, strategy, tactics, middlegame, sacrifice

Before I get into the details of my questions, I already know the f, g and h pawn attack tactics, bishops sacrifices such as the greek gift and Lasker's double bishop sacrifice among a few others and of course things such as the isolated queen pawn positions(which is usually something that ends up in the end game part).

So what I am looking for are some advanced middle game tactics, be it from books, online teachers or anything of the sort. I do not have the money to buy the rest of Daniel King's power play series and I already exhausted the few books I have. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The attacking manual](http://www.qualitychess.co.uk/products/2/23/the_attacking_manual_1_2nd_edition_-_by_jacob_aagaard/) by Jacob Aagaard might be just what you are looking for. I enjoyed it a lot. It contains instructive games and exercises.

Other good books on attacking: [Spielmann, The Art of Sacrifice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486284492), [Vukovic, The Art of Attack](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857444000),  [Christiansen, Storming the barricades](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1901983250).

Comment: After slightly checking the content of each book through some googling... I have to say you just found me some pretty damn good books. Thanks a lot man (ESPECIALLY The Art of Sacrifice book... Pure gold!)

Also if you're interested in end games "Domination in 2545 Endgame Studies by Kasparyan is pure gold as well :D Trying to return the favor although I have only read a few books on end games that ones is by far the best so far.